# Data exchange between android app and pc

Tags: android

I'm an experienced programmer but a rookie when it comes to android app development. My first  Android app needs to be able to exchange data with an existing Windows application on a PC, both devices being on the same LAN.

If the Android app could read and write a file on the PC, that would crack it. Is this easy to do? Can anyone point me at any examples?

Answer (score 1):

That would involve the host PC running some piece of software which would communicate over the LAN/Bluetooth with your app, and execute the required actions based on some events from your app.

There might be some dropbox/google drive apis, depending on what your aim is..  But I doubt you will avoid coding some sort of (small) desktop application for this purpose.

Comment: >>That would involve the host PC running some piece of software which would communicate over the LAN/Bluetooth with your app, and execute the required actions based on some events from your app.<< I am happy to do that. The system running on the PC was written by me in the first place. I'm just not sure how to code up the communications protocol on either end. We are talking about comparatively small data packets. As I said, the other solution that occurred to me would be for the PC end to have a networked folder that the Android app could access for read and write. Is that a viable option?